# centos updating system rpm

Tags: centos, redhat, tar, rpm

Hello I still new to this creating rpm from tar files but is it safe to create newer versions for linking lib tiff etc or would this break any other rpm that requires lib tiff or lib png as I would like to manage my own repo if possible but keeping it running latest versions as centos 6.6 uses old packages

Answer (score 0):

You just need to version that library. See

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Downstream_.so_name_versioning

Then rpmbuild correctly generate version for Provides and as far as it does not conflict with other requires of other installed packages, you can install it.